# How to monitor dynamic network interfaces with MRTG? (*nix)

Tags: linux, snmp, linux-networking, graph, mrtg

Every time I restart my OpenVPN tunnel it increments interface's number and breaks MRTG graph for the interface.

`IF-MIB::ifName.76 = STRING: tun_w`

after restart:

`IF-MIB::ifName.77 = STRING: tun_w`

Any way to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write a script that regenerates your MRTG configuration whenever the interface is restarted.  Also, adjust your MRTG configuration to target an interface based on the IP address.  Specifcally if you use `cfgmaker` to build your config, then pass the `--ifref=ip` option, assuming your IP is consistent.  If your IP isn't consistent, then check the man page other ifref options to see if any apply to your setup.

> What if conf files are edited by hand?

In your main configuration file you have created by hand use the include directive to include another configuration file.  Something like `Include: vpn-interface.cfg`.  Then update that configuration fragment with a script that happens on start/restart of the VPN.

Since you are using OpenVPN your might use the OpenVPN options `--up-restart`, `--up`, `--ipchange`, and `--down` options to link into the script that updates the configuration file for that VPN.

Compose your script that runs whenever the interface

Comment: and if conf files are edited by hand?

Answer (score 1):

When you create your MRTG cfg file, do not identify the interface by number.  Instead, identify it by ifName or similar.

For example this identifies the device by ifName,

```
Target[tun_w]: #tun_w:public@router
```

If the ifName is not unique, then try by ifDescr (use a backstroke to escape any spaces or colons in the description):

```
Target[tun_w]: \tun_w:public@router
```

Alternatively, use ifType (prefix with %) or Ethernet address (prefix with !)

One of these should allow you to uniquely identify the interface despite its ifIndex changing frequently.